# Scroll pages with mouse move

Tags: jquery, html

My html page contain the "Nestable" drag and drop menu. My problem is when I drag some thing and drop at the end of the page it needs to scroll the page down and vice versa. How it possible using jQuery or JavaScript???

Comment: What have you tried so far? place your code... We can't directly code for you friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this bit of code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/289/)

Maybe call this function on drag and drop, Also try playing with the height to figure out when you want the page to scroll up/down, currently its somewhere in the middle of your screen.

```
 $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   $("html, body").scrollTop(function(i, v) {
      var h = $(window).height();
      var y = e.clientY - h / 2;   //determins the y location where your scrolling starts
      return v + y * 0.1;          //0.1 determines the speed
    });
 });
```

**Edit:** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BYUdS/3/)  is a smoother transition, a bit more complex but you can still understand what is going on

Comment: added a smoother transition, previous one seemed laggy

Comment: Hai, Its working fine... Bt my need is when drag something that time it needs to move the page..bt using the first code any time mouse move..page also moving...